# Optimizing Sub query, sum and top functions

Tags: sql, subquery

This is my query

```
select   t.accountno  from tenant_info t where  
(
    select  sum(d.Bill_Amount) from billing_summary s , Billing_Detail d 
    where s.Id=d.Billing_Summary_ID and  s.id in 
      (select top 2 Id from Billing_Summary where Tenant_Info_ID = t.TenantId 
         order by bill_date desc)
) = 0
```

The number of records in tables are in millions, thats why this query gives result in like 3 minutes and until then the application timed out.I think the third sub query needs to be written better but can not come out with any solution.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: could you run 'explain select (...)', and print the result here.

Comment: It selects the top 2 bills(desc Date) of a specific Tenant and check if their sum is zero then it will return that record.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008.
I believe the 3rd sub query is taking most of the time, in with it had to join and select between millions of records.

Comment: i have the execution plan file. please let me know how to paste it here?
or should i send it to you.

Comment: Can you show a few samples of records from each data table, even if sample of 4 customers and 3-4 billing entries each and what/why you are only looking at the top 2 entries from billing summary.  Also, what if someone has more than one record on a given date.

Answer (score 0):

The above inquiry SQL statement from @Mustafa is clearly more elegant, but this performs faster.

SETUP TEST DATA:

```
    --/*
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('Tenant_Info', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Tenant_Info;
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Tenant_Info (
        TenantId            int IDENTITY(1, 1)
       ,AccountNo           varchar(10)
    )
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Billing_Summary', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Billing_Summary;
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Billing_Summary (
        Id                  int IDENTITY(1, 1)
       ,Tenant_Info_ID      int
       ,Bill_Date           date
    )
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Billing_Detail', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Billing_Detail;
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Billing_Detail (
        Id                  int IDENTITY(1, 1)
       ,Billing_Summary_ID  int
       ,Bill_Amount         decimal(28, 10)
    )
    GO

    -- ====================================================================
    -- CREATE THE Tenant_Info TEST DATA
    -- Turn 1 row into 1,048,576
    INSERT Tenant_Info (AccountNo) SELECT ''

    DECLARE @Count int; SELECT @Count = 0;
    WHILE @Count < 20 -- 20: 1,048,576  10: 1,024
      BEGIN
        INSERT Tenant_Info (AccountNo)
        SELECT AccountNo FROM Tenant_Info

        SELECT @Count = (@Count + 1)
    END

    UPDATE TI SET TI.AccountNo = CONVERT(varchar(10), (1000000000 + TI.TenantId))
    -- SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Tenant_Info TI

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Tenant_Info ON Tenant_Info (TenantId);
    -- ====================================================================



    -- ====================================================================
    -- CREATE THE Billing_Summary TEST DATA (12 MONTHS FOR EACH TENANT)
    DECLARE @Count2 int; SELECT @Count2 = 0;
    WHILE @Count2 < 12
      BEGIN
        INSERT Billing_Summary (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date)
        SELECT 1, DATEADD(MONTH, @Count2, '08/01/2012')

        SELECT @Count2 = (@Count2 + 1)            
    END

    -- Ensure that the Max Bill Date has the lowest Billing_Summary Id to 
    -- avoid the assumption that the Ids are in order
    DECLARE @MaxBillDate date;
     SELECT @MaxBillDate = MAX(Bill_Date) FROM Billing_Summary

    INSERT Billing_Summary (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date)
    SELECT TI.TenantId, BS.Bill_Date
      FROM Tenant_Info TI
      CROSS JOIN Billing_Summary BS
     WHERE TI.TenantId <> 1
       AND BS.Bill_Date = @MaxBillDate

    INSERT Billing_Summary (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date)
    SELECT TI.TenantId, BS.Bill_Date
      FROM Tenant_Info TI
      CROSS JOIN Billing_Summary BS
     WHERE TI.TenantId <> 1
       AND BS.Bill_Date <> @MaxBillDate

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Billing_Summary_1 ON Billing_Summary (Id, Tenant_Info_ID);
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Billing_Summary_2 ON Billing_Summary (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date);
    --SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Billing_Summary
    --SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Tenant_Info_ID) FROM Billing_Summary
    --SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Bill_Date) FROM Billing_Summary
    --SELECT * FROM Billing_Summary WHERE Tenant_Info_ID = 1
    -- ====================================================================



    -- ====================================================================
    -- CREATE THE Billing_Detail TEST DATA (2 LINES FOR EACH SUMMARY)
    INSERT Billing_Detail (Billing_Summary_ID, Bill_Amount)
    SELECT BS.Id, BS.Tenant_Info_ID as [Bill_Amount]
      FROM Billing_Summary BS

    INSERT Billing_Detail (Billing_Summary_ID, Bill_Amount)
    SELECT BS.Id, BS.Tenant_Info_ID as [Bill_Amount]
      FROM Billing_Summary BS


    DECLARE @MaxBillDateB date, @2ndMaxBillDateB date;
     SELECT @MaxBillDateB = MAX(Bill_Date) FROM Billing_Summary
     SELECT @2ndMaxBillDateB = MAX(Bill_Date) FROM Billing_Summary WHERE Bill_Date <> @MaxBillDateB

    UPDATE BD SET BD.Bill_Amount = 0
      FROM Billing_Detail BD
      JOIN Billing_Summary BS
        ON BD.Billing_Summary_ID = BS.Id
      JOIN (
            SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT A.* 
              FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT BS.Tenant_Info_ID
                      FROM Billing_Detail BD
                      JOIN Billing_Summary BS
                        ON BD.Billing_Summary_ID = BS.Id
                   ) A 
             ORDER BY NEWID()
           ) B
        ON BS.Tenant_Info_ID = B.Tenant_Info_ID
       AND BS.Bill_Date     IN (@2ndMaxBillDateB, @MaxBillDateB)

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Billing_Detail_1 ON Billing_Detail (Id);
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Billing_Detail_2 ON Billing_Detail (Billing_Summary_ID);
    -- SELECT BS.Tenant_Info_ID, SUM(BD.Bill_Amount) FROM Billing_Detail BD JOIN Billing_Summary BS ON BD.Billing_Summary_ID = BS.Id WHERE BD.Bill_Amount = 0 GROUP BY BS.Tenant_Info_ID
    -- ====================================================================

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    --*/
```

RUN THE INQUIRY SCRIPT:

```
    /*        
    -- ORIGINAL QUERY TAKING 3 MINUTES BY THE QUESTION ASKER
    SELECT COUNT(*) -- On my system this runs in about ~25 seconds for a 524,288 row result
      FROM (
                select   t.accountno  from tenant_info t where  
                (
                    select  sum(d.Bill_Amount) from billing_summary s , Billing_Detail d 
                    where s.Id=d.Billing_Summary_ID and  s.id in 
                      (select top 2 Id from Billing_Summary where Tenant_Info_ID = t.TenantId 
                         order by bill_date desc)
                ) = 0
           ) A
    --*/


    -- Start off getting the max bill date for each tenant
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tenant_MaxBillDate', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tenant_MaxBillDate;
    CREATE TABLE #Tenant_MaxBillDate (Tenant_Info_ID int, Bill_Date date);

    INSERT #Tenant_MaxBillDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date)
    SELECT BS.Tenant_Info_ID, MAX(BS.Bill_Date)
      FROM Billing_Summary BS
     GROUP BY BS.Tenant_Info_ID

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_MaxBillDate ON #Tenant_MaxBillDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date);


    -- Additionally, get the 2nd latest bill date for each tenant
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate;
    CREATE TABLE #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate (Tenant_Info_ID int, Bill_Date date);

    INSERT #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date)
    SELECT BS.Tenant_Info_ID, MAX(BS.Bill_Date)
      FROM Billing_Summary BS
      LEFT JOIN #Tenant_MaxBillDate TM
        ON BS.Tenant_Info_ID = TM.Tenant_Info_ID
       AND BS.Bill_Date      = TM.Bill_Date
     WHERE TM.Tenant_Info_ID IS NULL
     GROUP BY BS.Tenant_Info_ID

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate ON #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Bill_Date);


    -- This is necessary to avoid an incorrect assumpttion that the max summary id also has the latest bill date
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tenant_MaxBillSummary', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tenant_MaxBillSummary;
    CREATE TABLE #Tenant_MaxBillSummary (Tenant_Info_ID int, Billing_Summary_ID int);

    INSERT #Tenant_MaxBillSummary (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID)
    SELECT BS.Tenant_Info_ID, MAX(BS.Id)
      FROM Billing_Summary BS
      JOIN #Tenant_MaxBillDate TM
        ON BS.Tenant_Info_ID = TM.Tenant_Info_ID
       AND BS.Bill_Date      = TM.Bill_Date
     GROUP BY BS.Tenant_Info_ID

     CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_MaxBillSummary ON #Tenant_MaxBillSummary (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID);


    -- This is necessary in case the 2nd max summary id is also on the latest bill date
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate;
    CREATE TABLE #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate (Tenant_Info_ID int, Billing_Summary_ID int);

    INSERT #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID)
    SELECT BS.Tenant_Info_ID, MAX(BS.Id)
      FROM Billing_Summary BS
      JOIN #Tenant_MaxBillDate TM
        ON BS.Tenant_Info_ID = TM.Tenant_Info_ID
       AND BS.Bill_Date      = TM.Bill_Date
      LEFT JOIN #Tenant_MaxBillSummary TMM
        ON BS.Id             = TMM.Billing_Summary_ID
       AND BS.Tenant_Info_ID = TMM.Tenant_Info_ID
     WHERE TMM.Billing_Summary_ID IS NULL
     GROUP BY BS.Tenant_Info_ID

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate ON #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID);


    -- This will probably get the majority of cases where the 2nd max summary id is on the 2nd latest bill date
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate;
    CREATE TABLE #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate (Tenant_Info_ID int, Billing_Summary_ID int);

    INSERT #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID)
    SELECT BS.Tenant_Info_ID, MAX(BS.Id)
      FROM Billing_Summary BS
      JOIN #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillDate TM
        ON BS.Tenant_Info_ID     = TM.Tenant_Info_ID
       AND BS.Bill_Date          = TM.Bill_Date
      LEFT JOIN #Tenant_MaxBillSummary TMS
        ON BS.Id                 = TMS.Billing_Summary_ID
      LEFT JOIN #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate TMS2
        ON BS.Tenant_Info_ID     = TMS2.Tenant_Info_ID
     WHERE 1=1
       AND TMS.Billing_Summary_ID IS NULL -- Do not choose the same summary ID
       AND TMS2.Tenant_Info_ID    IS NULL -- Do not choose a tenant that has to summary entries for their max date
     GROUP BY BS.Tenant_Info_ID

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate ON #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID);


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords;
    CREATE TABLE #Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords (Tenant_Info_ID int, Billing_Summary_ID int);

    INSERT #Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID)
    SELECT Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID FROM #Tenant_MaxBillSummary
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID FROM #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_SameDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID FROM #Tenant_2ndToMaxBillSummary_2ndDate

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords ON #Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords (Tenant_Info_ID, Billing_Summary_ID);
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_#Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords2 ON #Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords (Billing_Summary_ID, Tenant_Info_ID);


    SELECT COUNT(*) -- On my system this runs in about ~14 seconds for a 524,288 row result
      FROM (
            SELECT TI.TenantId, TI.AccountNo
              FROM #Tenant_Top2BillSummaryRecords A 
              JOIN Tenant_Info TI
                ON A.Tenant_Info_ID = TI.TenantId
              JOIN Billing_Summary BS
                ON A.Billing_Summary_ID = BS.Id
              JOIN Billing_Detail BD
                ON BS.Id             = BD.Billing_Summary_ID
             GROUP BY TI.TenantId, TI.AccountNo
            HAVING SUM(BD.Bill_Amount) = 0
           ) A
```